# JQuery dialog() Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui-dialog

I get the error message shown below when I click the button: `($'#billing_button_addTime')`

> billingController.dialogAddTime.dialog
>   is not a function

billingController is created in `$(document).ready`.

```
function BillingController() {
    }
BillingController.prototype.dialogAddTime = $(document.createElement('div'));

BillingController.prototype.loadBillingContent = function () {
        //Load the main content    
        $("#content_area").load('/Content/HTML/billing.html', null, mainController.attachScrollBarsToCPOTable);

        //Pre-Load the Add Time Dialog
        $(billingController.dialogAddTime).load('/Content/HTML/billing_dialog_addTime.html', null, billingController.bindButtonAddTimeToHandler );
    }

BillingController.prototype.bindButtonAddTimeToHandler = function () {
    $('#billing_button_addTime').bind('click', billingController.buttonHanderAddTime);
}

BillingController.prototype.buttonHanderAddTime = function () {
    billingController.dialogAddTime.dialog({ modal: true });
}
```

Comment: Where are you defining lowercase billingController?

Comment: Where are you initializing billingController? Shouldn't you have `var billingController = new BillingController();` somewhere?

Comment: @mVChr - in $(document).ready

Comment: @scurker - in $(document).ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I boneheadedly forgot to include the JQuery UI script. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

BillingController.prototype.dialogAddTime = $('');

This does not look right to me.... You may have to do is to define the div in the html

```
<div id="billingDialog"></div>
```

And then in script use as follows:

```
BillingController.prototype.dialogAddTime = $('#billingDialog');
```

Hari Gangadharan

Comment: Thanks Hari. That is not where it is crapping out but I made a change to that line that should look better. ;)