# JQuery UI - "dialog is not a function" Hunh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I get the error message shown below when I click the button: `($'#billing_button_addTime')`

> billingController.dialogAddTime.dialog
>   is not a function

billingController is created in `$(document).ready`.

```
function BillingController() {
    }
BillingController.prototype.dialogAddTime = $(document.createElement('div'));

BillingController.prototype.loadBillingContent = function () {
        //Load the main content    
        $("#content_area").load('/Content/HTML/billing.html', null, mainController.attachScrollBarsToCPOTable);

        //Pre-Load the Add Time Dialog
        $(billingController.dialogAddTime).load('/Content/HTML/billing_dialog_addTime.html', null, billingController.bindButtonAddTimeToHandler );
    }

BillingController.prototype.bindButtonAddTimeToHandler = function () {
    $('#billing_button_addTime').bind('click', billingController.buttonHanderAddTime);
}

BillingController.prototype.buttonHanderAddTime = function () {
    billingController.dialogAddTime.dialog({ modal: true });
}
```

Comment: OK, I'll bite: where do you define the function "dialog"?

Comment: It wounds like you don't have the jQuery UI `.js` included correctly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery dialog() Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5426984/jquery-dialog-error)

Comment: @Nick Craver. Thank you very much. That was the answer....God I miss Java right now. Well it will get better.